# Visualize attendance over time data in a meaningful way

Tags: database, google-sheets, charts, report

I have data that looks like this

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+
|   Date    |    Time     | Initials | Location 1 | Location 2 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+
| 8/26/2019 | 11:00:00 AM | BI       |         39 |         40 |
| 8/26/2019 | 1:30:00 PM  | Kk       |         12 |          2 |
| 8/27/2019 | 2:30:00 PM  | BH       |         18 |         37 |
| 8/28/2019 | 3:30:00 AM  | BH       |         23 |         29 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+
```

The output should be something very similar to the Google Maps "Popular Times" graph.

[image: Popular Times Graph]

I would like to be able to visualize

1. A graph for each location in this style (attendance over time via hour), which is the average attendance per day of the week
2. I would also like to be able to specify a given date ex: 8/26/2019 and pull up the exact data for that date

So I figure either there can be a different graph for every location, or maybe have the various locations data show as different colored bars on the graph.

Ultimately I have this data in a spreadsheet and I'm not sure what would even be the best tool to use to report this data. I looked into data studio and google analytics and just using charts inside the sheet.

### However the issue seems to be:

Since the data can be both various dates and various times. I'm not sure how or which tools to use to group the data by a given day, or average the data for a given day of the week. I tried using pivot tables but I'm not sure how to report based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which tools to use to group the data by a given day, or average the data for a given day of the week

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A2:E, 
 "select A,count(A),sum(D),sum(E),sum(D)+sum(E),avg(D),avg(E),avg(D)+avg(E),max(D)+max(E),min(D)+min(E)
  where A is not null 
  group by A", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)
```

[image]

---

```
=QUERY(A2:E, 
 "select A,count(A),sum(D),sum(E),sum(D)+sum(E),avg(D),avg(E),avg(D)+avg(E),max(D)+max(E),min(D)+min(E)
  where A is not null 
  group by A
  pivot C", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

> need to figure out how to take this input and arrange by Day of the week

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A, TEXT(A2:A, "ddd"), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

> Also by hour instead of just by date

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A, TEXT(TIME(HOUR(B2:B), 0, 0), "hh:mm:ss"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is fantastic for grouping by specific date! Now I just need to figure out how to take this input and arrange by Day of the week, I.e. avg attendance for Mondays, Tuesdays, etc. Also by hour instead of just by date